# How do I setup a logger in my Matomo plugin Command class?

Tags: php, matomo, monolog

I am trying to create a logger just like that described in the Matomo documentation, but the dependency injection does not seem to be working.

The docs: https://developer.matomo.org/guides/logging

My class inside my plugin:

```
namespace Piwik\Plugins\MyPlugin;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Sync
{
  private $logger;

  public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
  {
      $this->logger = $logger;
  }

...
}
```

The class is being created in a Command `execute` function.

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
  $sync = new Sync();
```

The error:

> Uncaught exception: ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Piwik\Plugins\MyPlugin\Sync::__construct(), 0 passed in /Users/me/src/matomo/plugins/MyPlugin/Commands/SyncCommand.php on line 55 and exactly 1 expected in /Users/me/src/matomo/plugins/MyPlugin/Sync.php:14

Using:

- PHP 8.0.2
- Matomo 4.2.0

Comment: This is not a proper solution, but more of a temporary workaround, but I think you can still use the old logging interface: https://developer.matomo.org/3.x/guides/logging

For the new method you'd need to use Dependency Injection instead of directly initializing the class (https://developer.matomo.org/guides/dependency-injection). Something like `$sync = StaticContainer::get(Sync::class)` might work